# Android draw 9 patch graphic rounded corner get stretched?

Tags: android, android-drawable, nine-patch

We have made a draw 9 patch graphic for a button and other things that has rounded corner we have than set so the corners shouldnt stretch but when we implement it the corner looks blurred.

Here is the draw 9 patch image we use:
[image: button image]

Here it how it looks when implemented:
[image: button image]

I know you could create the rounded corners in code in this example but there are some other buttons/graphics we cant create by cpde because of shapes and other things where we have same issue.

Any idés why?

Comment: Where is it located in the project?

Comment: Where the graphic is located?

Comment: Is the image resolution as poor as 72 dpi?

Comment: @morto where did you put the nine-patch file and what device are you running on when it's blurred?

Comment: I put it in the drawable folder.
I have tried to do the image in higher dpi. 
I test both in simulator and Samsung Note 2.

Comment: You should put it to drawable-xhdpi in order to look good on Note 2.